# Header layout for multilines title using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

My current header looks like this. The second line of the header is touching the dividing line. My question is how to move the text upwards or the dividing line downwards so that the format looks nicer.[image]

The code in the main file is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} %set header type
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt} 
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load}
\chaptermark{\protect\parbox{.55\textwidth}{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load\strut}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide compilable documents, not just fragments only

Comment: Note the `titlesec` package has a `newlinestospace` option which converts any line break in titles to spaces for the header.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, new to this site and Latex. The question has been updated.

Comment: @bernard Thank you for your comment. touhami's method works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because of the `parbox`. A solution is by adding `\strut`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} %set header type
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt} 

\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load}
\chaptermark{\protect\parbox{.55\textwidth}{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load\strut}}
\chapter{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load}
\chaptermark{\protect\parbox{.55\textwidth}{Open Top Frustum Shells under Vertical Uniform Load\strut}}
\end{document}
```

[image]